# Docker - Is it possible to connect containers in the same host using weave

Tags: docker, docker-compose, weave

I am trying to connect multiple containers in the same host (aws server) using weave. But the docker run command doesn't give any output if I give

```
weave launch <aws-public-ip>
eval $(weave env)
```

I tried this with and without docker-compose..

I tried connecting multiple containers in different hosts using virtual box in my mac. That was working perfectly.

Is this possible using weave?

I know that we can achieve it using links in docker.. But I read somewhere that links will be removed in future and networking is the preferred way

Answer (score 0):

So Finally it is solved..Hope this helps others who are having the same issue.

When you launch weave like this

```
weave launch <aws-public-ip>
```

Weave looks for another weave peer and try to connect to it.. Thats why it hangs.

I got this info from the github page of weave:
https://github.com/weaveworks/weave/issues/1950

**So the solution is** to just do

```
weave launch
eval $(weave env)
```

from the host system

and reference your containers with

```
containerName.weave.local
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats right - we use the number of IP addresses provided on weave launch as a clue to the size of the initial quorum needed to bootstrap the IP allocator.  If you provide too many IP address, we'll fail to establish the quorum and you won't be able to allocate IPs, and therefore start containers.